# Encrypt using Rijndael in SQL and decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, rijndael

I need to use Rijndael encryption to encrypt a column. Currently I'm using C# code for both encryption and decryption. Currently I read records from a file using SQL Server Integration Services. The records are send to the column that are subsequently encrypted by a script. This takes a lot of time for files with more than 1000 records.

Can Rijndael encryption be achieved in SQL Server itself? When I need to show decrypted data on the screen, could I use Rijndael decryption of the that same data using a C# defined decryption routine?

Comment: you could make CLR stored procedure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to your Question is Yes! and [here is how](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15296/SQL-Encryption-and-Decryption-Library-Using-Rijnda)

The link provides the files that you have to build and then register with SQL server and then install its methods into SQL server. Author has well explained the steps.

Comment: Use better ***CLR stored procedure*** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx